# Brushless Motor/ESC Voltage Cut-off

Tags: esc, brushless-motors, transmitter, receiver

I got an ESC and brushless motor set for my RC car. After I finally got it to work, I put my car back together, but then when I turn on the transmitter and then the ESC, the motor emits a "beep" every 1/2 second. The ESC has a voltage cut-off, could this be the cause for the sound?

It also makes this sound, when I turn on the ESC without having the transmitter...

Comment: It may be voltage cutoff. It might also be the ESC connected wrong. Make sure the Signal and Ground are not swapped.

Comment: Once I charged the battery again, it did it's little song saying that it is connected, and ready to go. It was the low voltage cutoff. I had previously connected them wrong, but the motor didn't make any noise like that... the servo also didn't work, so I just switched the connection around.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple answer: Yes, it was the voltage cutoff.

I charged my batter hoping that it was the low voltage cutoff that was doing the error beeps. Once I tried it with the charged battery, it did the normal connection "song".

Like Kevin said, though, you need to make sure that the wires are connected correctly.